# Excel 2016, First Friday or Monday of year

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

If I have a year (In text Form so it can be changed by user) in cell J2.
How do I calculate which is first Friday or Monday of the year (Whichever comes first in the year)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest this rewording : "If I have a user enter a year in an Excel 2016 cell, how do I calculate whether that year has its first Monday come before the first Friday, or the reverse?"  Alas, I have no idea how to do this in Excel.